# How to model mongodb collections for Cassandra database (migration)?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

I am new to Cassandra and trying migrate my App from MongoDB to Cassandra

I have the following collections in MongoDB

```
PhotoAlbums
[
  {id: oid1, title:t1, auth: author1, tags: ['bob', 'fun'], photos: [pid1, pid2], views:200 }
  {id: oid2, title:t2, auth: author2, tags: ['job', 'fun'], photos: [pid3, pid4], views: 300 }
  {id: oid3, title:t3, auth: author3, tags: ['rob', 'fun'], photos: [pid2, pid4], views: 400 }
  ....
]

Photos
[
 {id: pid1, cap:t1, auth: author1, path:p1, tags: ['bob','fun'], comments:40, views:2000, likes:0 }
 {id: pid2, cap:t2, auth: author2, path:p2, tags: ['job','fun'], comments:50, views:50, likes:1, liker:[bob] }
 {id: pid3, cap:t3, auth: author3, path:p3, tags: ['rob','fun'], comments:60, views: 6000, likes: 0 }
 ...
]

Comments
[
  {id: oid1, photo_id: pid1, commenter: bob, text: photo is cool, likes: 1, likers: [john], replies: [{rep1}, {rep2}]}
  {id: oid2, photo_id: pid1, commenter: bob, text: photo is nice, likes: 1, likers: [john], replies: [{rep1}, {rep2}]}
  {id: oid3, photo_id: pid2, commenter: bob, text: photo is ok, likes: 2, likers: [john, bob], replies: [{rep1}]}
]
```

**Queries:**

- Query 1: Show a list of popular albums (based on number of likes)
- Query 2: Show a list of most discussed albums (based on number of
  comments)
- Query 3: Show a list of all albums of a given author on
  user's page
- Query 4: Show the album with all photos and all comments
  (pull album details, show photo thumbnails of all photos in the
  album, show all comments of selected photo
- Query 5: Show a list of
  related albums based on the tags of current album

**Given the above schema and requirements, how should I model this in Cassandra?**

Answer (score 1):

As I have experience with both Cassandra and Mongo, I'll take a shot at this.  The tricky part here, is that MongoDB allows for very loose restrictions around indexing and querying.  Cassandra has a trickier model in that respect, but one that should perform fast, at scale, if created correctly.  Also, the aspect of counting likes/views/comments on a photo or album can also get tricky, as you'll want to use Cassandra's `counter` type for that (which has its own challenges).

*Disclaimer*: Others may solve these problems differently.  And I may choose to solve them differently if my first attempt didn't perform.  But this is what I would start with.

To satisfy **Query 3** I would create a query table called `PhotoAlbumsByAuthor` and query it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PhotoAlbumsByAuthor (
 photoalbumid uuid,
 title text,
 author text,
 tags set<text>,
 photos set<uuid>,
 PRIMARY KEY(author,title,photoalbumid)
);

> SELECT * FROM photoalbumsbyauthor WHERE author='Malcolm Reynolds';
```

That will return all albums that the user Malcolm Reynolds has created, sorted by `title` (as title is the first clustering key).

For **Query 4** I would create comments as a [user defined type](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html) (UDT):

```
CREATE TYPE yourkeyspacename.comment (
 commenter text,
 commenttext text
);
```

Then I would create a query table called `PhotosByAlbum` and query it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PhotosByAlbum (
 photoalbumid uuid,
 photoid uuid,
 cap text,
 auth text,
 path text,
 tags set<text>,
 comments map<uuid,frozen <comment>>,
 PRIMARY KEY(photoalbumid,photoid)
);

> SELECT * FROM PhotosByAlbum WHERE photoalbumid=a50aa80a-8714-44b4-9b97-43ec4b13daa6;
```

When you add a comment to this table, the `uuid` key of the map is the commentid.  This way you can quickly grab all of the keys and/or values on your application side.  In any case, this will return all photos for a given photoalbumid, along with any comments.

I would solve **Query 5** in a similar way, by creating a query table (you should be noticing a pattern by now) called `PhotoAlbumsByTag` and query it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PhotoAlbumsByTag (
 tag text,
 photoalbumid uuid,
 title text,
 author text,
 photos set<uuid>,
 PRIMARY KEY(tag,title,photoalbumid)
)

SELECT * FROM PhotoAlbumsByTag WHERE tag='family';
```

This will return all photo albums with the "family" tag.  Note, that this is a denormalized structure of the `tags set<text>` used above, which means that a photo album will have one entry in this table for each tag it contains.  I thought about possibly reusing one of the prior query tables with a secondary index on `tags set<text>` (as Cassandra now allows indexes on collections) but secondary indexes don't typically perform well.  And you would still have to execute a query for each tag in the current album anyway (using a `SELECT` with the `IN` keyword is known to not perform well, either).

As for the first two queries, I would create specific tables to store the likes/views/comments counts like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PhotoCounters (
 photoid uuid,
 views counter,
 comments counter,
 likes counter,
 PRIMARY KEY (photoid)
);
```

When using the `counter` type, Cassandra requires that the primary key and counters be the only columns in that table (can't mix counters with non-counter columns).  And I would also process queries/reports on those offline, in an OLAP fashion, using Hadoop or Spark.  Hope this helps.